# How do you update a parent's Shared Value from a dynamic number of child Shared Values?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

I think my question can best be asked by providing a minimum example. Let's say I have a Parent component that renders a Sum. This Parent component can have n children that renders sliders. The final application must allow the user to slide the the sliders from 0 to 10 and as they do so the total Sum in the parent component should also update in real time.

With this in mind let's layout the 2 components, starting with the Parent:

```js
function Parent({ numChildren }) {
  const sum = useSharedValue(0)
  const sumText = useDerivedValue(() => `Sum: ${sum.value}`)
  return (
    <>
      <ReText text={sumText} />
      {Array.from({ length: numChildren }).map(() => (
        <Slider />
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

And the child (Slider) component:

```js
const WINDOW_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width

function Slider() {
  const translateX = useSharedValue(0)
  const startX = useSharedValue(0)
  const gesture = useMemo(
    () =>
      Gesture.Pan()
        .onUpdate((e) => {
          // for simplicity we will ignore bounding the slider to the windows width
          translateX.value = startX.value + e.translationX
        })
        .onEnd(() => {
          startX.value = translateX.value
        }),
    []
  )

  // This value should somehow be reflected in Parent's Sum
  const sliderValue = useDerivedValue(() => {
    return interpolate(
      translateX.value,
      [0, WINDOW_WIDTH],
      [0, 10]
    )
  })

  const handleStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{ translateX: translateX.value }],
    }
  })

  return (
    <View> // We'll pretend this is the slider's container
      <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
        <Animated.View style={handleStyle} />
      </GestureDetector>
    </View>
  )
}
```

How would you approach getting the parent's Sum to show the total sum of all the sliders as the user interacts with the sliders? I've tried a number of things including:

- passing the `sum` shared value to the `<Slider />` component
- creating a shared value with a map `useSharedValue({})` that is passed to the children to update with a unique key
- using state and state updates for `sum` instead of shared value

One of the biggest hurdle I run into is that I cannot create a dynamic number of useSharedValues because of React hooks top level rule. But running into this usually indicates there is an architectural fault with my current approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty nasty solution to this. Would still appreciate other ideas on how to solve this. For now this is what I've come up with a solution that adds a SharedValue to the parent to store all the slider values. Also the parent needs to pass the `sum` shared value to the Slider component so that it can update it when the gesture is active.

```js
function Parent({ numChildren }) {
  const sum = useSharedValue(0)
  const sliders = useSharedValue(new Array(numChildren).fill(0))
  const sumText = useDerivedValue(() => `Sum: ${sum.value}`)
  return (
    <>
      <ReText text={sumText} />
      {Array.from({ length: numChildren }).map(() => (
        <Slider sum={sum} sliders={sliders} />
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

```js
const WINDOW_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width

function Slider({ sum, sliders }) {
  const translateX = useSharedValue(0)
  const startX = useSharedValue(0)
  const gesture = useMemo(
    () =>
      Gesture.Pan()
        .onUpdate((e) => {
          // for simplicity we will ignore bounding the slider to the windows width
          translateX.value = startX.value + e.translationX

          const value = interpolate(
            translateX.value,
            [0, WINDOW_WIDTH],
            [0, 10]
          )
          sliders.value[index] = value
          sum.value = sliders.value.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0)
        })
        .onEnd(() => {
          startX.value = translateX.value
        }),
    [translateX, startX, sum, index]
  )

  const handleStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{ translateX: translateX.value }],
    }
  })

  return (
    <View> // We'll pretend this is the slider's container
      <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
        <Animated.View style={handleStyle} />
      </GestureDetector>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Ideally the `<Slider />` component shouldn't know anything about the sum.